# Please check my Javascript Snippet. It's a greasemonkey script for FB Mobwars

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Hey guys, I'm practising my Javascript programming by developing greasemonkey scripts, theoretically it would improve my javascript coding cause it's raw javascript.

So now, im coding a script for Mobwars facebook. It's a game where you kill people, steal stuffs, create mobs, etc etc.

To understand this better, here's the screenie of the page:

[alt text http://www.picamatic.com/show/2009/03/18/08/11/2877480_703x486.png](http://www.picamatic.com/show/2009/03/18/08/11/2877480_703x486.png)
What I'm trying to do is to scan the page, and get the Name of the job and display it to the user.

I want to get the text Mugging, House Burglary, Stoplight Car Theft etc etc

The text have a color property which is set to silver.

Look at my code, I tried it in Firebug but it doesn't even alerted..

```
var jobs = {};

jobs.scan = function() {
    var tagHolder = {};
    var availJobs = {};
    var jobContents = dom.get("app8743457343_content");
    var rData = dom.getElementsByClass(rowData, jobContents, "tr");
    for(var i = 0; i < rData.length; i++) {
        var rChildren = rData[i].childNodes;
        for(var j = 0; j < rChildren.length; j++) {
            if(rChildren[j].tagName === "B") {
                tagHolder.push(rChildren[j]);
            }
        }
        for(var k = 0; k < tagHolder.length; k++) {
            if (tagHolder[k].color == "silver") {
                availJobs.push(tagHolder[k].textContent);
            }
        }
    }
    return alert(availJobs[0]);
}

jobs.scan();
```

Just tell me what's wrong with the code.. I'll just tweak this code and maybe if i managed to fix it, ill report it here again. Thanks

Comment: I figured out why it didn't work!! Because of the getElementsByClass..

I need to pass a string but I didn't encapsulate the rowData with " "..

Anyway, im still having problems.. Im trying to solve it man! Thanks for the valuable tips guys!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a custom "getElementsByClass" function? DOM doesn't have a getElementsByClass method. Perhaps you were trying to borrow code from somewhere else and didn't realise this?

There are plenty of getElementsByClass methods available on the internet

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Perchik, if you don't provide the definition of the functions you use, plus the html it's supposed to run on, we can't really help you to check your code.

Anyway, I still see two things you can change. The first one is to initialize your arrays as arrays, and not as empty objects. You can't use the `push` method if your variable is not an array:

```
var tagHolder = new Array();
var availJobs = new Array();
```

The second one is to use jQuery or any other javascript library that can make your life easier. In GreaseMonkey, you can use `@require` :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Script Name
// @namespace      namespace
// @include        http://www.website.net/*
// @require        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
```

The `@required` scripts are retrieved **when you add** your script to GreaseMonkey: if you want to use that, you'll have to remove your script and reload it. GreaseMonkey will then keep a local copy of the `@required` scripts and load them when needed.

With jQuery, your code would then look like that:

```
var jobs = {};

jobs.scan = function() {
    var tagHolder = new Array();
    var availJobs = new Array();
    $("#app8743457343_content b").each(function() {
        tagHolder.push(this);
        if ($(this).attr("color") == "silver")
            availJobs.push($(this).text());
    });
    return alert(availJobs[0]);
}

jobs.scan();
```

Comment: IC, I didn't know that I can't use the push method if I didn't use the new Array() constructor. But isn't this an array too? var array = {}?

Hey the required part is cool! I didn't even know that exist. TY

Answer (score 1):

+1 for ybo, your answer was spot on given the information available. I had a quick look at the relevant markup from the Mob Wars page, and it looks like this:

```
<div id="app8743457343_content" fbcontext="db6ca1f1773e">
 ...
   <b style="font-size: 15px; color: silver;">Mugging</b>
 ...
```

I modified your solution based on the actual markup to:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Mob Wars Job List
// @namespace     namespace
// @description   Script to summarise available Mob Wars jobs.
// @include       http://apps.facebook.com/mobwars/jobs/
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function() {
var jobs = {};
jobs.scan = function() {
    var availJobs = new Array();
    $("#app8743457343_content b").each(function() {
        if ($(this).css("color") == "silver")
            availJobs.push($(this).text());
    });
    return alert("Available jobs:\n" + availJobs.join('\n'));
}
jobs.scan();
});
```